# React Native label animation with onFocus event

Tags: react-native, animation

Hello I am trying to create a phone number with 'react-native-phone-number-input'. But the problem is I have label animation which triggers with onFocus or this kind of things. But phone number input doesnt't have onFocus prop.
And now I have no idea how can I handle with it?

Thanks in advance

Here is my phoneNumber component

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [formattedValue, setFormattedValue] = useState('')
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false)
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false)
  const phoneInput = useRef<PhoneInput>(null)
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(true)

  const focusAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current

  const scale = focusAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.75],
  })

  const translateY = focusAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [20, 0],
  })

  const translateX = focusAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [8, -150],
  })

  let borderColor = isFocused ? colors.primary : colors.gray600
  let labelColor = isFocused || value ? colors.primary : colors.gray400

  return (
    <View>
      {showMessage && (
        <View>
          <Text>Value : {value}</Text>
          <Text>Formatted Value : {formattedValue}</Text>
          <Text>Valid : {valid ? 'true' : 'false'}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      <>
        <PhoneInput
          ref={phoneInput}
          defaultValue={value}
          defaultCode='TR'
          layout='first'
          onChangeText={text => {
            setValue(text)
          }}
          onChangeFormattedText={text => {
            setFormattedValue(text)
          }}
          placeholder='Telefon Numarası'
          containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
          textContainerStyle={styles.textContainerStyle}
          textInputStyle={styles.textInputStyle}
          codeTextStyle={styles.codeTextStyle}
          flagButtonStyle={styles.flagButtonStyle}
          countryPickerButtonStyle={styles.countryPickerButtonStyle}
        />
      </>
    </View>
  )
}
```

here what I got with it

[image: phone input]

here what I want to create

[image: what I want to create]

Comment: Merhaba, try wrapping the component with a touchablewithoudfeedback component and give it an onpress={animation}

Comment: Merhaba, I found out that  PhoneInput has 'textInputProps' prop . So I put onFocus in it like below,
`textInputProps={{ onFocus() { setIsFocused(true) }, }}`